# How to access properties in async await return object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Why I can't access object properties with a `.` in async await return object?
I know that I can access the properties like below.

```
let val1 = await call(3);
let val2 = await call(4);
```

but I'm interested if this can be done

```
let v = await call(3).val + await call(4).val;
```

```js
const call = (x) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                val: x
            });
        }, 3000)
    })
}

const dummy = async () => {

    //let val1 = await call(3);
    //let val2 = await call(4);
    //alert(value.val + val2.val);
    let v = await call(3).val + await call(4).val;
    alert(v);
}

dummy()
```

Comment: Not exactly shorter: `let v = await Promise.all([call(3), call(4)]).then(res => res.reduce((a, c) => a + c.val, 0));` this way you don't have multiple handwritten lines, and it takes 3 seconds total.

Comment: I think it should work like this: `let v = (await call(3)).val + (await call(4)).val;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the `await` and the expression to await in parens. Then access the property.

```js
const call = (x) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        val: x
      });
    }, 3000)
  })
}

const dummy = async() => {
  let v = (await call(3)).val + (await call(4)).val;
  alert(v);
}

dummy()
```

Do note that doing it this way, you're awaiting 3 seconds for the first call, then awaiting another 3 seconds for the second call. Unless the second call is somehow reliant on the first, I suggest you do the following:

```js
const call = (x) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        val: x
      });
    }, 3000)
  })
}

const dummy = async() => {
  // Call both in parallel
  let val1 = call(3);
  let val2 = call(4);
  
  // Await for both
  let v = await Promise.all([val1, val2]);
  
  // *then* add
  alert(v[0].val + v[1].val);
}

dummy()
```

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to await the value of the `val` property *of the promise*.

You need to await the *promise* and then read the `val` property from the result: `(await call(3)).val`

```js
const call = (x) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                val: x
            });
        }, 3000)
    })
}

const dummy = async () => {
    let v = (await call(3)).val + (await call(4)).val;
    alert(v);
}

dummy()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why I can't access object properties with a `.` in async await return
>   object?

Because `call` returns a `Promise` and thus has no property `val`. When you `await` the returned Promise, the expression `await call(x)` will eventually resolve to `{val: x}`, which you can then use `.val` on.

Thus, you can either `await` each call separately and save the returned object in their own variables, or wrap your expression `await call(x)` in parenthesis of their own, such that you are getting the `.val` of the resolved value, not the promise:

```js
const call = (x) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        val: x
      });
    }, 3000)
  })
}

const dummy = async() => {
  let v = (await call(3)).val + (await call(4)).val;
  alert(v);
}

dummy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the call does not return a direct result object. It is returning a promise which will resolve value in .then callback. You can await this call.

```js
const call = (x) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                val: x
            });
        }, 3000)
    })
}

const dummy = async () => {

    //let val1 = await call(3);
    //let val2 = await call(4);
    //alert(value.val + val2.val);
    let v = await call(3).then(result => result.val) + await call(4).then((result)=> result.val);
    alert(v);
}

dummy()
```