# Difference betweeen Two line of same code

Tags: javascript, async-await

can someone explain to me the differenec between the two line of code. In my atom editor the prettier changes the first to second.

```
(await fetchSearchResults(state.requestConfig, context))?.facilities ?? [] )
```

and

```
await fetchSearchResults(state.requestConfig, context)?.facilities ?? [] )
```

Comment: It just removed the unnecessary brackets from around the `await x(...)` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier changes the whole thing to follow the rules given in a Prettier config file.
In your **specific case**, the `(await fetchSearchResults(state.requestConfig, context))` is useless, hence why Prettier strips it.

Meanwhile, it may be quite important in a classic async context as explained in the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215664/difference-betweeen-two-line-of-same-code/72215865?noredirect=1#comment127590641_72215865). Maybe the optional chaining is somehow tricking Prettier here, not sure.

---

The default Vue2 ESlint configuration comes with `plugin:vue/essential` and `eslint:recommended` as defaults.
Here is [a link](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/) where you could get more details as of why.

If it's **Prettier only**, check the [options part](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) of the documenation or a `.prettierrc` config file in your project (or above).

Comment: It's not the same, though: `await foo().bar` means that `foo()` executes, then `.bar` is read from it *and that value is awaited*. While `(await foo()).bar` means to first await the result of `foo()` then take the property `bar` from it. If `foo()` returns a promise then `await foo().bar` is wrong, as it reads `bar` from the promise. Compare [`foo()` returns a promise](https://jsbin.com/rutopazuzi/1/edit?js,console) and [`foo().bar` returns a promise](https://jsbin.com/redereweji/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ hm, I always thought that the left part was awaited before reading the right part. I don't usually chain things like that, hence why I may be wrong. Still, would ESlint + Prettier strip that if it had a different meaning? I have to say that I trust those tools pretty well and never had any issues so far.

Comment: I've no idea which tool changed this code. But the semantics are absolutely not the same. It *might* be that `fetchSearchResults()` does not return a promise and nothing in the code is asynchronous. Then the brackets would be superfluous. The `await` would technically not be needed then, however, removing it *can* have more impact, as an `await` will still pause an async function and with asynchronicity this can lead to different results if the execution stops or doesn't stop in the middle of `fetchSearchResults()`. Overall, the change is strange.

Comment: Just double checked and yeah indeed, the meaning is quite different. In case of a promise, you'll need to wrap the async call into some `()` to then access a key from it. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The two lines are ***not*** the same and any automated change between these two is *most likely* incorrect.

To simplify, the difference is between:

1. `(await foo()).bar`
2. `await foo() .bar`:

Due to [the operator precedence of `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218744/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-await) the second code (`await foo().bar`) will:

1. Execute `foo()`
2. Read the property `bar` from it
3. `await` that value

Which can be written as:

```javascript
const functionResult = foo();
const result = await functionResult.bar;
```

While the first code uses [the grouping operator `()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) to [change the order of operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112239/how-to-access-properties-in-async-await-return-object) to:

1. Execute `foo()`
2. `await` that value
3. Read the property `bar` from it

Which can be written as:

```javascript
const functionResult = await foo();
const result = functionResult.bar;
```

This absolutely makes a difference if the function returns a promise:

```js
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve({ bar: "hello world" });
}

async function main() {
  console.log( await foo() .bar); // undefined - `foo()` returns a promise and there is no `bar` property
  console.log((await foo()).bar); // "hello world" - since the promise resolves to { bar: "hello world" }
}

main();
```

It also makes a difference if `foo()` is synchronous but the `bar` property is a promise:

```js
function foo() {
  return { bar: Promise.resolve("hello world") };
}

async function main() {
  console.log( await foo() .bar); // "hello world" since the promise resolves to that string
  console.log((await foo()).bar); // Promise (check the browser console)
}

main();
```

The only time it does not make a difference is if there is no asynchronous code (which means the `await` probably should not be there):

```js
function foo() {
  return { bar: "hello world" };
}

async function main() {
  console.log( await foo() .bar); // "hello world"
  console.log((await foo()).bar); // "hello world" 
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those brackets as long as you are not going to use the promise result straight after as in the example below

```
(await fetchSearchResults(state.requestConfig, context))?.facilities ?? [] )?.someMethod()
```

but the line is already getting quite long so you are probably best assigning the promise result to a variable.